# Installing GTX 970 Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nvidia, display-resolution, nvidia-geforce

I have been following the answers of many questions on here and I have finally managed to install the correct drivers and my GTX 970 works with Ubuntu 16.04.

The only problem is that it's locked at a low resolution, 1024x768 at 4:3 aspect ratio.

How can I enable it to go full 1080p?

Output for

```
lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D':

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM204 [GeForce GTX 970] (rev a1)
Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] GM204 [GeForce GTX 970]
Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_367, nvidia_367_drm
```

My integrated Intel graphics aren't showing up anymore, probably because I've got the GPU plugged in via HDMI rather than the motherboard.

I installed the drivers by following the answer from cl-netbox on here:

[How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers/680826#680826)

Comment: This means you did not install drivers correctly. How did you install drivers? Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to disable SecureBoot in your UEFI (BIOS) settings.

Comment: When I installed the driver it asked if I wanted to, and I hit yes. It is turning it back on, on reboot?

Comment: I just tried to disable secure boot and the option is greyed out. I tried creating an admin and user password but it was still greyed out - and locked to enabled